# Text Wrapping in Gedit

Tags: text, indentation, word-wrap, gedit

Is is possible in Gedit (The GNOME text editor) to indent a wrapped line of text?

For Example:

```
if (x > y) {
    System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJ
    KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
}
```

instead of:

```
if (x > y) {
    System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with GEdit out of the box, but this is a request that's [**being worked on**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/318517).

Comment: is it really that hard to implement?